# Proper way to change entity parameters through form

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-core

Lets imagine that we have *User* entity:

```cs
public class User
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string StatusMessage{ get; set; }
    public string PasswordHash { get; set; }

    public Group Group { get; set; }
    public Referal Referal { get; set; }
}
```

Where *User*-to-*Group* have many-to-many relations and *User*-to-*Referal* have one-to-many relations. Both of them have Foreign Key constraints on *User*.

I'm as *User* suddenly realized that my current status doesn't represent my personality fully enough - so I decided to change it.
We have simple form to submit new status.

```html
@model User

<form asp-antiforgery="true" method="post" role="form">
    <div class="validation" asp-validation-summary="ModelOnly"></div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <div>
            <input hidden asp-for="Id" type="number" name="Id" value="@Model.Id">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="Status">Status:</label>
        <div>
            <input required asp-for="Status" type="text" name="Status">
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

And two actions to deal with it.

```cs
[HttpGet("account/edit")]
public IActionResult Edit(int accountId, string Status)
{
   User user = db.Users.SingleOrDefault(p => p.Id == accountId);
   return View(user);
}

[HttpPost("account/edit")]
public IActionResult Edit(int Id, string Status)
{
   User user = db.Users.SingleOrDefault(p => p.Id == accountId);
   user.StatusMessage = Status;
   db.SaveChanges()
   return RedirectToAction("MainView");
}
```

Doesn't saw anything wierd? In post method we again connected to our DB to get our hands on proper entity so any relations it have will be saved. It's good way if we have only couple of fields to update. But it became more and more ugly if we have 10-15 fields or more.

```cs
[HttpPost("account/edit")]
public IActionResult Edit(int Id, string Status, string FavouriteGirl, string LastWatchedTVShow, int NumberOfFingers, DateTime YearOfFirstKiss, string DogName)
{
   User user = db.Users.SingleOrDefault(p => p.Id == accountId);

   user.StatusMessage = Status;
   user.FavouriteGirl = FavouriteGirl;
   user.LastWatchedTVShow = LastWatchedTVShow;
   user.NumberOfFingers= NumberOfFingers;
   user.YearOfFirstKiss= YearOfFirstKiss;
   user.DogName = DogName;

   db.SaveChanges()
   return RedirectToAction("MainView");
}
```

It's convenient in a way, that we excplicitly state which fields will be changed, but they became hardcoded and we could look after changes in view.

A good way to deal with it is to pass *User* object.

```cs
[HttpPost("account/edit")]
public IActionResult Edit(User user)
```

But actually I cant find any good way to bind it to entity.

```cs
[HttpPost("account/edit")]
public IActionResult Edit(User user)
{
   //None of this will work

   User userFromDb = db.Users.SingleOrDefault(p => p.Id == user.Id);
   userFromDb = user;
   db.SaveChanges();
   //we just changed reference to variable, no effect on entity

   user.Group = userFromDb.Group;
   user.Referal = userFromDb.Referal;
   db.SaveChanges();
   //will cause FK constraint errors
}
```

And in the end we will be down to updating fields manually but from class `userFromDb.StatusMessage = user.StatusMessage`

So I want to know if there any better way to update entity than just manually updating it's fields?

Answer (score 1):

You could use `AutoMapper` to implement the update . For your scenario ,  User-to-Group have many-to-many relations and User-to-Referal have one-to-many relations , use the join table to implement the many-to-many relationship ,you could define them like below:

`User` Model , `UserGroup` Model ,`Group` Model , `Referal` Model

```
public class User
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public string Gender { get; set; }

    [MaxLength(30)]
    public string FirstName { get; set; }

    [MaxLength(30)]
    public string LastName { get; set; }


    [EmailAddress]
    public string Email { get; set; }

    [Phone]
    public string Phone { get; set; }

    public string StatusMessage { get; set; }

    public List<UserGroups> UserGroups { get; set; }
    public List<Referal> Referals { get; set; }
}

public class UserGroups
{
    public int UserId { get; set; }
    public User User { get; set; }
    public int GroupId { get; set; }
    public Group Group { get; set; }
}

public class Group
{
    public int GroupId { get; set; }
    public string  GroupName { get; set; }
    public List<UserGroups> UserGroups { get; set; }
}

public class Referal
{
    public int ReferalId { get; set; }
    public string ReferalName { get; set; }

    public int UserId { get; set; }
    public User User { get; set; }
}
```

`UserForUpdateDto` model and `GroupViewModel` model for mappering

```
public class UserForUpdateDto
{
    public int UserId { get; set; }
    public string Status { get; set; }

    public  List<Referal> Referals { get; set; }
    public List<GroupViewModel> Groups { get; set; }
}
public class GroupViewModel
{
    public int GroupId { get; set; }
    public string GroupName { get; set; }
}
```

Create `UserProfile` class

```
public class UserProfile: Profile
{
    public UserProfile()
    {
        CreateMap<UserForUpdateDto, User>()
            .ForMember(des=>des.StatusMessage,opt=>opt.MapFrom(src=>src.Status))
            .ForMember(des => des.Id, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.UserId))
            .ForMember(des=>des.Referals,opt=>opt.MapFrom(src=>src.Referals))
            .ForMember(des => des.UserGroups, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.Groups))
            .AfterMap((src,des)=> {
                foreach (var group in des.UserGroups)
                {
                    group.UserId = src.UserId;
                }
            });
        CreateMap<GroupViewModel, UserGroups>()
            .ForMember(des => des.Group, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src));

        CreateMap<GroupViewModel, Group>();

        CreateMap<User, UserForUpdateDto>()
            .ForMember(des => des.UserId, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.Id))
            .ForMember(des => des.Status, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.StatusMessage))
            .ForMember(des => des.Referals, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.Referals))
            .ForMember(des => des.Groups, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.UserGroups));
        CreateMap<UserGroups, GroupViewModel>()
            .ForMember(des => des.GroupId, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.Group.GroupId))
            .ForMember(des => des.GroupName, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.Group.GroupName));

        //CreateMap<Group, GroupViewModel>();

    }
}
```

Controller

```
 // GET: Users/Edit/5
    public async Task<IActionResult> EditTest(int? id)
    {
        if (id == null)
        {
            return NotFound();
        }

        var user =await  _context.Users
            .Include(u=>u.Referals)
            .Include(u=>u.UserGroups).ThenInclude(ug=>ug.Group)
            .SingleOrDefaultAsync(u=>u.Id==id);

        if (user == null)
        {
            return NotFound();
        }

        var userForUpdate = _mapper.Map<UserForUpdateDto>(user);

        return View(userForUpdate);
    }

    // POST: Users/Edit/5
    // To protect from overposting attacks, please enable the specific properties you want to bind to, for 
    // more details see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=317598.
    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public async Task<IActionResult> EditTest(int id, UserForUpdateDto userForUpdate)
    {
        if (id != userForUpdate.UserId)
        {
            return NotFound();
        }

        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            try
            {
                var user = _context.Users.AsNoTracking()
                    .Include(u => u.Referals)
                    .Include(u=>u.UserGroups)
                        .ThenInclude(ug => ug.Group).SingleOrDefault(u => u.Id == id);
                _mapper.Map(userForUpdate,user);

                _context.Users.Update(user);
                await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
            }
            catch (DbUpdateConcurrencyException)
            {
                if (!UserExists(userForUpdate.UserId))
                {
                    return NotFound();
                }
                else
                {
                    throw;
                }
            }
            return RedirectToAction(nameof(Index));
        }
        return View(userForUpdate);
    }
```

About AutoMapper with Asp.Net Core , you could refer to  https://sensibledev.com/asp-net-core-automapper/